# data filtering query

Tags: oracle

My Table has data which looks like

```
REF_NO  PRODUCT  MTR 
1       200       20
1       200       21
1       300       35
1       400       42
2       200       21
2       399       31
```

Now I desire to rows where REF_NO and PRODUCT are same but MTR is different.

## NEEDED RESULT IS:-

```
REF_NO  PRODUCT  MTR 
1       200       20
1       200       21
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.REF_NO, t.PRODUCT, t.MTR
from (
    select REF_NO, PRODUCT    
    from MyTable
    group by REF_NO, PRODUCT
    having count(distinct MTR) > 1
) tm 
inner join MyTable t on tm.REF_NO = t.REF_NO 
    and tm.PRODUCT = t.PRODUCT
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/303ff/2)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got the needed query while writing this question.

```
select a.REF_NO, a.PRODUCT, a.MTR 
  from MYTABLE a, MYTABLE b
where a.REF_NO = b.REF_NO, a.PRODUCT = b.PRODUCT 
   and a.MTR <> b.MTR;
```

Comment: How did this `where a.REF_NO = b.REF_NO, a.PRODUCT = b.PRODUCT ` work?

Comment: This will (once modified to compile) give you duplicate rows when there are more than two rows of data for a given REF_NO/PRODUCT combination.

Comment: Shouldn't there be `AND` in place of `,` here - `where a.REF_NO = b.REF_NO, a.PRODUCT = b.PRODUCT`?